# How to restart a Triggered Send from the AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

I have defined a Triggered Send based on a sendable Data Extension and an EMail AMPScript. I have assigned a external key to the Triggered Send and is sending emails when I create a POST request to the endpoint https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/external_key/send

I would like to know if there's a way to restart the Triggered Send programatically. I know there's a dashboard UI I can use but I'm not interested in do it manually.

Do you know how to do it? I have tons of Triggered Sends and I'd like to automate the pause/publish/restart process for each TS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

This is the most optimized solution I could find using AMPScript - albeit part of it is done in SSJS, but that part greatly reduces the code weight and optimizes the speed of the script.

As I was unsure which triggers you wanted to pause or restart, I filtered based on just 'currently active'.

```
%%[

/************************************

Retrieve Request - list of all Triggered Sends

*************************************/

SET @rr = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")  
SetObjectProperty(@rr, "ObjectType", "TriggeredSendDefinition")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","CustomerKey")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","Name")  
AddObjectArrayItem(@rr,"Properties","TriggeredSendStatus")   


/* Invoke the Retrieve Request API */

SET @tsd = InvokeRetrieve(@rr, @Status, @RequestID)  



/*******************************************

FOR loop - to iterate and update all Active Triggers

*******************************************/


FOR @c = RowCount(@tsd) DOWNTO 1  DO    

    SET @row = Row(@tsd ,@c)   
    SET @TSDName = Field(@row ,'Name')   
    SET @TSDKey = Field(@row ,'CustomerKey')
    SET @TSDStatus = Field(@row, 'TriggeredSendStatus')

    IF @TSDStatus == "Active" THEN

]%%

<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");

var tsdName = Variable.GetValue("@TSDName");
var tsd = TriggeredSend.Init(tsdName);

var pause = tsd.Pause();
var publish = tsd.Publish();
var start = tsd.Start();
</script>


%%[

    ENDIF

NEXT @c
]%%
```

---

I had the same sort of issue and it took a large chunk of my life to solve.

Reference this question/answer for more info on my exact issue: [SOAP API to 'publish' a TriggeredSendDefinition?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165548/soap-api-to-publish-a-triggeredsenddefinition/165565#165565)

As I am assuming you want to do a pause, publish and run - See below for API calls which will do a full restart on the triggered email interaction.

You just need to do the requests via the [AMPScript API functions](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/).

See below for [sample SOAP envelopes to accomplish this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214157&language=en_US&type=1):

**Pause**

```
<!--***pause***-->

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-452336374" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
        <!-- This section here is only necessary if you are targeting a Welcome Email within a Business Unit -->
            <Client>
               <ID>YOUR_MID</ID>
            </Client>
        <!--END-->
            <CustomerKey>TriggeredSend-customer-key-goes-here</CustomerKey>
            <TriggeredSendStatus>Inactive</TriggeredSendStatus>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Publish**

```
<!--***publish***-->

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-452336374" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>MC_USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
        <!-- This section here is only necessary if you are targeting a Welcome Email within a Business Unit -->
            <Client>
               <ID>YOUR_MID</ID>
            </Client>
        <!--END-->
            <CustomerKey>TriggeredSend-customer-key-goes-here</CustomerKey>
            <RefreshContent>true</RefreshContent>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Restart**

```
<!--***restart***-->

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-452336374" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
        <!-- This section here is only necessary if you are targeting a Welcome Email within a Business Unit -->
            <Client>
               <ID>YOUR_MID</ID>
            </Client>
        <!--END-->
            <CustomerKey>TriggeredSend-customer-key-goes-here</CustomerKey>
            <TriggeredSendStatus>Active</TriggeredSendStatus>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: You can use te ampscript API functions which mimic soap. I apologize they are just soap envelope samples, not ssjs.

Comment: @MarioRuiz - I made some edits to my answer that may better help solve your issue.

Comment: put it into a content area (inside classic) then call that content block with a SSJS script activity. You can then put that into an automation in Automation Studio.

Comment: Its hard to beat the SSJS functions I added in my edit, could you share your current solution? I am always curious about different ways to solve issues and finding the best ones.

Comment: Thanks man, this is absolutely useful!

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 2500 triggered sends in your BU, use this code which kind of pages through all available triggered sends. SOAP calls in general respond with a max of 2500 records.

Please use the external key to init the triggered send, not the name.

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1");

// Retrieve API call to get all triggered send definitions

var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "TriggeredSendDefinition");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "CustomerKey");
Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "TriggeredSendStatus");


// do while loop to do paging if there are more than 2500 triggered sends definitions

do {

    var results = [0,0];
    var rows = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, results);

    var runstatus = results[0];
    var requestId = results[1];

    if (rows != null) {

        // loop through all triggered send definitions

        for (var i in rows) {

            var key = rows[i].CustomerKey;
            var status = rows[i].TriggeredSendStatus;
            var now = Now();

            // if triggered send status is active, pause, publish, start triggered send definition

            if (status == "Active") {

                var tsd = TriggeredSend.Init(key);

                var pause = tsd.Pause();
                var publish = tsd.Publish();
                var start = tsd.Start();

            }
        } 
    } 

    rr.ContinueRequest = requestId;
    
} while (runstatus == "MoreDataAvailable")
```

Comment: Your code works but it is lack of `</script>` at the end of the code.