# Append an Exclusion script in all Triggered Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I have successfully added an Exclusion Script and tested the Triggered Send using  different scenarios

```
(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("MyDataExtension", "Environment", Environment)) < 1)
OR
(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("OtherDE", "Variable", Value)) < 1)
```

However I'd like to add it to tons of other Triggered Sends....

I'd desire to avoid doing it manually as I have too many, Is it possible?

Comment: Consider Auto-Suppression lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [How to restart a Triggered Send from the AmpScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174380/how-to-restart-a-triggered-send-from-the-ampscript) I found in the soap definition (https://webservice.s7.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl) that exists a ExclusionFilter field that is associated to the exclusion script, so the next call do the job.

As a note: recall escape the **<** per &lt ;

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
   <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-452336374" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>soapUsername</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">soapPassword</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"></wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2016-09-02T15:15:52.741Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
        <Options/>
        <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
           <Client>
               <ID>MID</ID>
            </Client>
            <CustomerKey>ck</CustomerKey>
            <TriggeredSendStatus>Inactive</TriggeredSendStatus>
            <ExclusionFilter>(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("MyDataExtension", "Environment", Environment)) &lt; 1) OR (ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("OtherDE", "Variable", Value)) &lt; 1 </ExclusionFilter>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```