# Cannot Perform action on TriggeredSend object via WSProxy?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, triggered-send, wsproxy

I'm trying to perform an action (Start, Pause, Publish) on a Triggered Send via WSProxy but with no success so far.

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");
//140643
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var action = ["Start", "Pause", "Publish"];
var opts = {};
var props = {"CustomerKey": 140643};
var req = prox.performItem("TriggeredSend", props, action[1], opts);
Write(Stringify(req));

</script>
```

And the status message of the response was: "*Cannot perform Perform on objects of type TriggeredSend*"

Can I ask if it's possible to achieve this via WSProxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot Perform on a Triggered Send. According to this chart, it only allows Create, Update and Delete:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/supported_operations_for_objects_and_methods.html

[image]

Comment: So there is no way at the moment to do actions on Triggered Send object via WSProxy but the native functions for Triggered Send? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_triggeredSendFunctions.html

Comment: @DucLe - you can via the Update Method. See this answer for more info (Shows sample SOAP envelopes that you can translate to WSProxy) https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174380/how-to-restart-a-triggered-send-from-the-ampscript#174394

Comment: @Gortonington Thank you for the great reference! I will post an answer based on my converted version

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Gortonington answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174380/how-to-restart-a-triggered-send-from-the-ampscript#174394). I could convert it using WSProxy as below:
"Inactive" status equals "Pause"
"Active" status equals "Start"
And RefreshContent equals true meaning Publish

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var updateObject = [
    {
    CustomerKey: 140642,
    TriggeredSendStatus: "Inactive"
    //RefreshContent: true
    },
    {
    CustomerKey: 140643,
    TriggeredSendStatus: "Inactive"
    //RefreshContent: true
    }];

var options = {SaveOptions: [{'PropertyName': '*', SaveAction: 'UpdateOnly'}]};
var req = prox.updateBatch('TriggeredSendDefinition', updateObject, options);
Write(Stringify(req));
</script>
```