# Refresh Email template -Transactional Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, administration, transactional-messaging-api

I've an account with dozen of "Transactional Journeys Email" and every time that I make a fix/change on the template (used by the email in the trigger) I have to manually go on each trigger open it then go to email Activity and save it to apply the changes.

Have you found a solution to "republish" all triggers in the same time or a way to save time on this operation (like you can do with lovely triggered sends)?

I've tried to use the API using Postman but seems as time consuming as the manual way.

#### UPDATE

An other issue I've found on simply republish the trigger using the manual way (but also via API) is that if you have updated the content of the TEMPLATE that email is based on the email (also after saving...) will not be updated, you have to open and re-select the email.
Also if the content inside the TEMPLATE are only references.

Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 2):

I could see a few routes that could be used here:

#1: You might want to consider about using [reference content block](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_dm_reference_content_block.htm&type=5) in the email. This content block type will reflect the change to the journey without needing to refresh the journey.

#2: Refresh the email triggered send in the Transactional Journey. To do this, you would need to *"Pause - Publish - Start"* the email triggered send.

You can read the [answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174380/how-to-restart-a-triggered-send-from-the-ampscript#174394) to be aware how it can be done in SSJS and modify it to fit with your need. IMHO I would convert it to use with WSProxy.

One tip here: the email triggered send customer key for Transactional Journey is the **Event Definition Key** of the transactional journey.

#3: Pause and then Resume the Transactional Journey will help to refresh the email triggered send. In this route, you can do it manually or use API calls

[Pause a Journey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/JourneyPauseByDefinitionId.html)

[Resume a Journey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/JourneyResumeByDefinitionId.html)

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to take a look on links u posted. Your first point in not correct if you use referenced content in Template (not in the email) if you update it the change will not reflect in the email inside the JB you need to republish it. If the change is on a referenced content direct placed inside the email (not in the template) you not need to republish.

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguous wording, I was trying to say the the content block in the email not the email template

Comment: No no, you are right. But my problem is that I've some content included inside a Template in order to "BLOCK CHANGING" when some non Tech people use for create new mail. :)

Comment: Unfortunately your attached answer and WS proxy can't work with Transactional Messaging API. Because them not under the standard SSJS AMPSCRIPT feature.
The only way is to get (VIA API) the list of triggers and then (one by one) stop and resume it. But should be API consuming. :/

Comment: Hi Frogmouth, you are talking about the #2 approach right? The key here is we only refresh (pause -publish - start) the triggered send within the Transactional Journey. The triggered send customer key will be used to update the "TriggeredSendDefinition". I am sure this will work. FYI I converted the Soap Envelope XML into WSProxy for my work

Comment: Maybe I'm not right but actually I'm tolking about TRANSACTIONAL MESSAGING non TRIGGERED SEND. If you create Transactional Journey Email the only one email activity inside the JB is a TRANSACTIONAL MESSAGING EMAIL.
I try using the script u suggest but it retrieve only the TRIGGERED SEND from my env not the Transactional Messaging Triggers.

Comment: It does have the triggered send there... It is the Email activity inside the transactional journey. Anyway, the last approach is also fine in my opinion..

Comment: Sorry mate but, No triggered send in transactional Journey.
However I'm working on a script that work with API. :(

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had to overcome similar issue lately. Apart from the content block you can simply go into the transactional journey

- open the email activity
- select in drop down "Activity summary"

[image]

- "Preview & Test" or "Select different message" - either preview it with contact or reselect same message
- Reselect message and click "Done" or go back when in "Prieview & Test" after you personalized the template

[image]

This will refresh the template.

EDIT: For multiple templates you need to create dummy suppression list for transactional channel it will republish all templates.

[original source of the global update by cloudkettle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU9KQhnXP54)

Comment: Yes, that is the way but if you have lot of transactional triggers (as me) this method in very very time consuming and with an hight error probability.

Comment: Have you figured it out? I know for marketing emails when you disable / enable supression list all templates refreshes. I do not know if there is suppression list for transactional email but if there is you can try this approach

Comment: Actually I have found it :) the ultimate trick.. it was by adding dummy supression list for transactional channel which will update all journeys at once. Now only you can find API to create one and delete supression list, so you can trigger it from anywhere 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aU9KQhnXP54

Comment: Very intersting Tip! Work also for content block lead by a templare?