# Using API to Pause and Resume the triggered sends in MC created from Salesforce CRM

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, api, managed-package, triggered-send

I have created a triggered send (TS) from the Salesforce CRM using the MC Connect. To activate and deactivate the triggered sends in the CRM we have the button on the triggered send as shown below:
[image]

My main goal is to Pause/Resume the triggered send in MC that I created in Salesforce CRM. If I use the SOAP Api to Update the triggered send, the status is returned as OK, but there has been no update that I see on the TS in MC. When asked the support team, they said that the API will not work for the triggered send that are created from the CRM. Is there any way through which I can resume/pause the triggered sends that are created from the CRM. Or is there any way through which I can use the Activate/deactivate button in the crm code so that I can automate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Pause / Publish / Start the triggeredsend. I don't see why this wouldn't work for any triggered send that exists in SFMC

there is a great example in this post:

[How to restart a Triggered Send from the AmpScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174380/how-to-restart-a-triggered-send-from-the-ampscript/174394#174394)